# mysql + php speed up

Tags: php, mysql, performance

php script 1 -INSERT 500 record per second and
php script 2 -UPDATE some data to that table (500 per second)

Web application SELECT data to the database to view data, draw statistic, etc

My problem is, it take long loading time to view data while the application inserting/updating data to table same time.

can anyone provide a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't design your application in such away that it inserts 500 records per page-view?

Comment: You need two mysql servers - master and slave. Update on master, select from slave

Comment: hi. the php scripts are web service API. the script is accesses 500 time per second by different user

Comment: The problem is that the DB table is locked during the inserts/updates. You may be able to improve the code so it locks the database for less time, but can't really tell you how without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `SELECT` clauses are mostly aggregate data or it's not mission critical that they be absolutely accurate every time they are called, you could try changing the isolation level to `READ COMMITTED`, or `READ UNCOMMITTED` which should give you a speed increase on the `SELECT` clause. You can read about the differences here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use just one query for inserting:

Example:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,value) VALUES (1,2), 
                                    (2,3), 
                                    (3,4),
                                     ...
```

On some condition that applies to UPDATEs too

### Edit

Based on your comment you can use `INSERT DELAYED`

Or you can use apccache or memcached to initially store the values in the memory than flush it into db each X time with the query above

Comment: each data is inserted by different user using HTTP POST. i means this script will be executed 500 time by different user